# Android java - Trying to use the emulator phone camera

Tags: java, android, camera

Hi I am trying to take a photo with the function below:

```
  public void requestPicture(View view) {

        if (!(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY))){
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_camera, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if( intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null ){
                Toast.makeText(this,R.string.no_app,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            else {
                String perm = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
                if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if( ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, perm) ) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        alert.setTitle(R.string.permission_neccesary);
                        alert.setMessage(R.string.storage_rationale);
                        alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
                        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialogInterface, i) ->
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{perm}, PICTURE_PERM));
                        alert.show();
                    } else
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{perm}, PICTURE_PERM);
                } else
                    sendPicture();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I don't know the cause but it is saying to me that I don't have the neccesary application. So it is getting at the second if statement. I am using the same code in another application and it is working so I don't know the cause of it.

In case it could help to resolve the problem I attach my manifest too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eus.ehu.intel.tta.matematikon">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logoa"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MatematikOn">
        <activity android:name=".pl.view.activities.GaiaActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".pl.view.activities.Test1Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".pl.view.activities.GaiaSortuActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".pl.view.activities.ForoGaiakActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".pl.view.activities.HaiserakoErronkaActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".pl.view.activities.HasieraActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".pl.view.activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It has the same permission than the example that works.
Could you help me?

Comment: If you post images of code, please also copy/paste or type the actual code directly into the post. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Posts in which essential text is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Comment: I have updated it, any suggestion?